# how to make the decorator in a regex pattern textbox unselectable?

Tags: javascript, css

Here is a screenshot of [regextester.com](https://www.regextester.com/):

[image: screenshot]

Users can only select the spaces between the preset pattern decorators, how to achieve this? I inspected the stylesheets, still have no clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to utilize [`contentEditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content), here's a simplified recreate of *regextester* input:

```js
document.querySelector('.editor').addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.currentTarget.querySelector('.input').focus();
});
```

```css
.editor .input {
  outline: none;
}

.editor *:not(.input) {
  opacity: 0.5;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="editor">
  <span>/</span>
  <span class="input" contentEditable="true"></span>
  <span>/g</span>
</div>
```

---

Using pseudo elements is also a good idea since there are natually unselectable:

```js
document.querySelector('.editor').addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.currentTarget.querySelector('.input').focus();
});
```

```css
.editor .input {
  outline: none;
}

.editor .input::before, .editor .input::after {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.editor .input::before {
  content: '/';
}

.editor .input::after {
  content: '/g';
}
```

```html
<div class="editor">
  <span class="input" contentEditable="true"> </span>
</div>
```